# Different role react redux applicant architecture

Tags: reactjs, redux

So for a webapp that uses react redux, a webapp normally will contain few folders like reducers, actions, containers, components, store.js and app.js. Now I want to have admin management dashboard for says an ecommerce system. For normal user they can manage their profile, checkout, add to chart etc but for admin he can add item, adjust stock etc, so how would the app structure look like?

It seems like I have to have 2 set of reducers, actions, containers, components, store.js because they are different thing. Maybe I can reduce some of the components.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may have as many reducers, actions, components etc. as you want. Just split up the components. You might end up with a large amount of components. But please stick to the StackOverflow Q&A format and do not ask for personal opinions. To design the structure, this github repo helps me: https://github.com/alexnm/re-ducks

Comment: @Larce many other author didn't structure their app that way, the repo shows an opinionated approach.

Answer (score 0):

With React / Redux it's mostly in your hands how you structure your application.

You do not need different reducers/actions or components. All you need to do is have some sort of separation within your application on what a User can do and cannot do. Again it's up to you how you structure it. For example I would have a folder called Common (Pages all users can see like Login) and a Folder for Super user (Admin). Considering that the admin can see all pages the simple user can see which are going to be in the Common folder.

From there all you need to do is set some sort of authentication method to check if a user is a Super user or a Normal user. For instance if a Normal user alters the **URL** to go to a page that they are not supposed to see, you will need to implement a method to prevent that. But that has nothing to do with your file structure.